# "Filter failed" from hplip

Tags: printing, cups, hplip

Problem Description - Unable to print

Device name : HP LaserJet M1005 MFP USB printer

OS : Linux 3.8.13-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT x86_64 GNU/Linux

Error Description :

1. Cups is working well and fine.
2. I am able to access localhost:631
3. Hplip is installed
4. Tried to print a PDF file.
5. After issuing print command, the print queue shows the error `"Processing - Not connected?"`
6. Further exploration for the print job error led me to an error "Filter failed"

What I have tried so far :

- Removed and added the printer through the cups web interface
- Tried installing the printer using hp-setup under root.

I am not sure what to do at this point. Could someone please tell me what to do or atleast where to look next to have a chance at solving my problem...

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/cups/error_log`?

Comment: I do not have a file called error_log in that directory. I do have a file called error_log.1 in that directory. The contents are a few pages long. I didn't think it would be a good idea to paste the whole thing here, so I have pasted it on pastebin. Here it is [link](http://pastebin.com/1ZD4qR1k)

Comment: Your symptoms could be a sign of a [missing proprietary plugin](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=611255). But the resolution should then be to [run `hp-setup`](http://hplipopensource.com/node/309). What did the setup wizard do? Did it install an additional proprietary driver? Please run `hp-check -t` and post the output.

Comment: can you share the output of lpstat -a -v

Comment: @Salton Output of `lpstat -a -v` is          `HP_LaserJet_M1005 accepting requests since Wed 29 May 2013 03:44:00 PM IST`                                 `device for HP_LaserJet_M1005: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_M1005?serial=KJ20Y9V`

Comment: @Gilles `hp-check -t` produced a file called `hp-check.log` in my home directory. I have posted the contents of the file to pastebin. Here is the [link](http://pastebin.com/SrFMhcFG)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see this line in the logs (`/var/log/cups/error_log`):

```
m_Job initialization failed with error = 48
```

A web search indicates that many HP printers, including yours, require a proprietary plugin to print, and that you will see this message if you haven't install this plugin (e.g. [Fedora bug #611255](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=611255)).

The logs from `hp-check -t` confirm this:

```
error: Required plug-in status: Not installed
```

So it seems that you need to [install the HPLIP binary plugin](http://hplipopensource.com/node/309). The easy way is to run the `hp-setup` wizard and enter your printer model, it should install the appropriate plugin, but it doesn't seem to have worked in your case. As `hp-check` tells you, try `hp-doctor`, which may find the missing plug-in. If that doesn't work either, run the more basic tool `hp-plugin`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to finally get it to work but the procedure was a little different. I tried hp-doctor. Apart from a few missing optional dependencies, there was one missing dependency called `hpaio`. I use arch linux. Didn't know what package provide the functionality of `hpaio`. After some searching, I installed `sane` and modified `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` to include the text "hpaio" and "hpoj" in 2 seperate lines. And then, in arch linux ... `python` points to `/usr/bin/python3`. `hp-doctor` needs `/usr/bin/python2`. I changed linnk and ran hp-doctor again. It worked.

Comment: On my lubuntu 16.04 I managed to get my printer working with **sudo apt-get install hplip cups** and **hp-setup -i** (without sudo)

Comment: I am utterly baffled by this answer — and that it worked. I've had an HP multifunction printer that I've been printing to like clockwork for something like 6 years now from the same Archlinux host. This morning it wouldn't print with this error, and adding the proprietary plugin fixed the problem (when reinstalling / restarting the entire subsystem and all related packages did nothing). What changed I don't know. Why did this printer suddenly decide it wouldn't work without some piece I've never had before?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a full disk. The filter needs to create temporary files in `/var`. This was the cause of problems for me.

Answer (score 0):

Gilles answer is correct.

In cups Add Printer, some printers in the list have requiring plug-in statement. So, even after the printer is added, it still does not have a proprietary, not open-source, plug-in. Use **hp-plugin** after installing **hplip**.

Answer (score 0):

Recently had the same "filter failed" problem with my vintage HP Deskjet 845c printer.
Solved by replacing hpcups driver with foomatic.